# Where is my gavatar?

Tags: support, user-accounts

This site does not show my gavatar as other SE sites do.

Why? How can this be fixed?

And what should I ask so that it pass my question?

Comment: Not sure what's wrong, but you should be able to copy your other gavatar image and paste it into your Biology account. It happened to me once using Area 51.

Comment: Never copied gavatars between other SE sites, it was copied automatically.

Comment: There was a merge of another user account into yours just after you switched gravatars, this likely set your avatar to the default image from the other user. I can't say anything else about the merge, this was something an SE employee did (moderators can't merge users), you probably created a second account accidentally at some point.

Comment: btw, you don't have a 'gavatar'. :P

Answer (score 2):

Here's the easy way to update your dp. **Go to one of your other accounts** (I used [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1171620/suzan-cioc) as an example for the screenshots)

**Once on that account, click 'edit'**

[image]

Then scroll down to the bottom of the page, and **click 'Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities'**

[image]

As all your SE accounts have the same message in the bio, the only change this will bring is to update your bio dp to the one on SO and your other accounts.